# Loading location model for English NER in OpenNLP 1.5.3

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I am using *OpenNLP 1.5.3* and I would like to perform NER for location names in English texts. For this purpose I have downloaded the corresponding model (en-ner-location.bin) from the next url:

http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/

The problem is that when I try to perform NER in a text using this model with the following command:

```
./Opennlp/bin/opennlp TokenNameFinder en-ner-location.bin < Text.txt > Text.txt.ner_en_loc
```

I get the following error:

```
Loading Token Name Finder model ... failed
IO error while loading model file 'en-ner-location.bin'
Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:193)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:416)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readDouble(DataInputStream.java:468)
    at opennlp.model.BinaryFileDataReader.readDouble(BinaryFileDataReader.java:53)
    at opennlp.model.AbstractModelReader.readDouble(AbstractModelReader.java:75)
    at opennlp.model.AbstractModelReader.getParameters(AbstractModelReader.java:146)
    at opennlp.maxent.io.GISModelReader.constructModel(GISModelReader.java:75)
    at opennlp.model.GenericModelReader.constructModel(GenericModelReader.java:59)
    at opennlp.model.AbstractModelReader.getModel(AbstractModelReader.java:87)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.GenericModelSerializer.create(GenericModelSerializer.java:35)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.GenericModelSerializer.create(GenericModelSerializer.java:31)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.loadModel(BaseModel.java:231)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.<init>(BaseModel.java:181)
    at opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel.<init>(TokenNameFinderModel.java:110)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.namefind.TokenNameFinderModelLoader.loadModel(TokenNameFinderModelLoader.java:41)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.namefind.TokenNameFinderModelLoader.loadModel(TokenNameFinderModelLoader.java:32)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:62)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.namefind.TokenNameFinderTool.run(TokenNameFinderTool.java:59)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.CLI.main(CLI.java:225)
```

Is there something wrong in my command or is it a bug for this model in OpenNLP 1.5.3?

Comment: Maybe the file is damaged, did you try downloading it again? The size should be 5,110,658 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file was damaged. I downloaded it again and everything worked correctly.